# error: printing txt file in c++ only print "0"

Tags: c++

I am just trying to print this simple txt file. It opens correctly because it is successful per the code, but I am only get "0" when there is certainly more data in there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

struct item{
   string item;
   string type;
   int price;
   };


ifstream data("messageBoard.txt");
data.open("messageBoard.txt");

if (data.is_open()){
    cout<<"success"<<endl;
    }

cout<<data<<endl; //shouldn't think just print the entire file? It 
//is only printing 0, and I am also getting "success" printed as well

 while(getline(data, word, '\r')){
    cout<<"here"<<endl;

        stringstream ss;
        int wordindex=0;
        if(lineindex>0){
        ss<<word;
```

Comment: No, no. Don't *assume* what should happen. Look up the documentation for the functions you use. You cannot print a file, you can print its contents. Get the contents stored in some container (e.g. a string) and print that.

Comment: I am using getline to store a string of data, but the loop is getting skipped over.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cout<<data<<endl; //shouldn't think just print the entire file? It 
> //is only printing 0, and I am also getting "success" printed as well
> ```

No, that should not print the file. `data` is a file stream. There is no overloaded operator to insert a file stream into an output stream.

Perhas you intended to stream the contents instead:

```
cout<<data.rdbuf()<<endl;
```

`rdbuf` returns the associated stream buffer of the file stream, and there is an operator overload to insert a stream buffer into an output stream. The behaviour of the operator is to extract from the buffer until end of file is reached.

---

The reason why inserting a stream into a stream can compile at all is because prior to C++11, streams were implicitly convertible to a type that can be inserted into a stream.